# Doesn't show thumbnail in media section

Tags: umbraco7

I started to have some problems with my umbraco solution, i can't see thumbnails in the media section anymore.

I have attached some images that shows the "error".

[image]

[image]

I tried to rebuild solution, rebuild index, and so on.

Please if anyone has some information about this answer this post.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I found the problem, I had an Property "upload" on the image, that's what killed it all, I changed it to a media picker, and all works again.

Answer (score 0):

Does your data-type on the media item for the uploaded image have the alias `umbracoFile`? I think the thumbnail preview looks for this data-type to create the thumbnail.

If this does not help, have a look in the Developer Toolbar at the actual thumbnail and see what path it is looking for and why its not finding it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in my case the problem was that I had a "upload"-property on the image, I changed that to a media-picker, and it all worked again..